# MySQL query to change variable product price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to change the prices for variable products in woocommerce. I tried with below MySQL query to do it,

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = price_value 
WHERE post_id = variation_id AND meta_key = '_sale_price';
```

but its updating only in backend(DB and admin area) not in front-end. Actually in front-end its not showing sale price also.
As I'm not good at SQL, is there any code snippet or WooCommerce hook which allows me to change the price for a variable product?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If you want to change the Product Price which is on **Sale** you have
>   to update both `_sale_price` and `_price` with same value.

```
//for Regular Price
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = diff_price_value 
WHERE post_id = variation_id AND meta_key = '_regular_price';

//for Price
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = price_value 
WHERE post_id = variation_id AND meta_key = '_price';

//for Sale Price
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = price_value 
WHERE post_id = variation_id AND meta_key = '_sale_price';
```

**ADDED**
If you want to merge all the above query into a single query you can use this one:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = CASE
                   WHEN meta_key = "_regular_price" THEN diff_price_value
                   WHEN meta_key = "_price" THEN price_value
                   WHEN meta_key = "_sale_price" THEN price_value
                   ELSE meta_key
               END
WHERE post_id = variation_id
  AND meta_key IN ("_regular_price", "_price", "_sale_price");
```

---

Also you have to delete WooCommerce product price caching which is stored in `wp_options` table under **`_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_{{post_id}}`** **and `_transient_wc_var_prices_{{post_id}}`** in `option_name`

```
DELETE
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE (`option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_%'
    OR `option_name` LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_%')
```

*All the above query is tested and worked for me.*

**Before running this query do take a database backup**

Reference: [Copy WooCommerce products Sale prices to regular prices and reset Sale prices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879385/5019802)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. Is there any way they can be combined to a single query,?

Comment: @karbyl_subbu: I have updated my answer, please give it a try.

Comment: @RaunakGupta , I need your help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805478/how-to-update-sale-price-woocommerce3-0-variable-product)

Comment: For some reason, updating the table just doesn't affect the products' prices.
And I've changed all of them (price, regular and sale).
Is there some kind of cache or data saved in arrays somewhere?

Comment: @rantebi: Yes you also need to delete all the cache price that is stored in `wp_options` table. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879385/5019802), I'll update this answer as well with in few min.

Comment: Thank you!
I found a solution, perhaps it's the same as the link you suggested. 
First I had to make sure I updated all these meta_keys:
"_price","_regular_price", "_sale_price", "_min_variation_price", "_max_variation_price", "_min_variation_regular_price", "_max_variation_regular_price", "_min_variation_sale_price", "_max_variation_sale_price"
Second, I edited the weight field in all of the products I have (From 0 to 0 with bulk edit) and that probably caused the caches to flush.