# Updating product prices cache issue using a SQL query in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce, product, price

I have a SQL script that is supposed to synchronize and adjust regular price comparing the text document uploaded daily on server.

New prices are written to database, and I see them when looking at database. They show in `_regular_price` field properly. Problem is that frontend shows old prices .. until I manually just re-update each product in backend. Since i have thousands of products it is ineffective and tedious.

What am I missing?

Comment: Variable product prices are cached in woocommerce

Comment: @LoicTheAztec how would you solve it programmatically?

Comment: you need to delete price cashing `_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_` and `_transient_wc_var_prices_` check this answer last part https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548895/5019802

Comment: @RaunakGupta What I see when looking at database is that mostly single products are affected by this non-change in price and variable products seem ok.

Comment: Correction: After closer look I see that there are simple products and variable products that are affected by this non-changed price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Variable product prices** are cached in `wp_options` table as transient…

So you will need also to delete through SQL using for each variable product ID something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `wp_options`.`option_name` LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_1234'
DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `wp_options`.`option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_1234'
```

Where **`1234`** (at the end) is the variable product ID.

So programmatically (where `$product_id` is the dynamic variable product ID):

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query( "
    DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options 
    WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}options.option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_var_prices_$product_id'
" );

$wpdb->query( "
    DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options 
    WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}options.option_name LIKE '_transient_wc_var_prices_$product_id'
" );
```

This will remove the targeted variable product cache…

---

**Other products** *(simple for example)* not cached… When updating prices there is 2 cases:

1) The product is on sale:

- `_price` and `_sale_price` will have the discounted product price.
- `_regular_price` will have the normal product price (non discounted)

2) The product is NOT on sale:

- `_price` and `_regular_price` will have the normal product price.
- `_sale_price` will be empty

> So `_price` and `_regular_price` need always to be updated…

Comment: What I see when looking at database is that mostly single products are affected by this non-change in price and variable products seem ok.

Comment: Correction: After closer look I see that there are simple products and variable products that are affected by this non-changed price. Does your solution include simple products as well?

Comment: @Wed Single products are not affected… I have just tried now, updating a simple product price in the database and the price displayed change also immediately in frontend/backend of wordpress/woocommere … so there is something else that is caching the data in your website…

Comment: unfortunately for me even single products are affected.
Take an example of this simple product.
Backend: https://pasteboard.co/H8kYwZB.png
Frontend: https://pasteboard.co/H8kZREp.jpg

I appriciate your help, This is really perplexing for me.

Comment: @Wed I have updated my answer regarding simple products (other product types), may be this will help you… Now as I don't have your problem, I can't help you anymore on this.

Comment: What i figured out is if I just update this single product its price is different ion backend and frontend, but if i make a change in backend (i.e. add ",00" at the end of regular price amount) it changes in frontend.

Comment: @Wed What you can try to see if it makes something: via phpMyAdmin chose a product ID (`post_id`) in `wp_postmeta` table and update values for 
 keys `_price` and `_regular_price` with the same amount… Now check in backend/frontend… be sure that you have disable cache plugins or hosting cache.