# Woocommerce price caching

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_sale_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price_tmp' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_sale_price_tmp' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_price_tmp' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_min_variation_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_max_variation_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_min_variation_regular_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_max_variation_regular_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_min_variation_sale_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(ceil(meta_value*0.9) - 0.1 )WHERE meta_key = '_max_variation_sale_price' AND meta_value != ''AND meta_value > 10;

DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%\_transient\_%')
```

trying to update prices in MySQL, deleted the whole transient options, no w3 total cache or other caching plugins installed. Yet, the UI still showing the old value, but interestingly the admin product edit showing the new value, only after I click update again, then the UI change. Why ?

Comment: did you try clearing the browser cache or viewing in another browser?

Comment: @Matts Hi, I have already view them in new browser incognito mode.

Comment: Kindly check "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861390/updating-product-prices-cache-issue-using-a-sql-query-in-woocommerce". I hope this helps. Best regards.

Comment: @MrEbabi I have seen that answer, it's not a solution for me, I have applied those, it does not work. But I found the problem, it was the multicurrency plugin WOOCS that cause this issue, I have deactivated it now. Thanks